# What's the word for undo a wish?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

The opposite of grant a wish. Like someone who will be the adversary of genie

Comment: For a wish not yet granted, "deny". For one already granted, "retract".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I think ‘undo’ works (as in the title). What I *think* OP wants is someone who undoes/retracts wishes.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context.  How do you want to use this phrase?